# How to get fixed USB device names in Linux

Tags: linux, debian, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a relatively short question concerning USB device handling: How is it possible to map a USB device to a fixed device.

I know there are ways using udev rules, but I want complete instructions showing how to do it and what tools to use (if there are any). So show me how you would map the following USB drives to a fixed device.

### 1 USB HDD

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1058:1110 Western Digital Technologies, Inc.
```

should go to:

```
/dev/sdc
```

### 1 USB flash drive

`Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1b1c:1ab1`  <- unknown vendor, actually its CORSAIR VOYAGER

should go to:

```
/dev/sdd
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use [UUID](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-finding-using-uuids-to-update-fstab/)s or Volume Labels, you don't need fixed device names.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [udev rules](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) to manually force the device IDs etc...